# Text Widget in Footer for just 1 page template

Tags: widgets, footer

I am building a wordpress website and I want to show a text widget in the footer just for one page template. That widget shouldnot be seen for other pages. Is there any possible way for that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use a Plugin that adds contextual [conditions to Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=conditional%20widgets&sort=)
2. Only output the `dynamic_sidebar()` in the page template in question. For example, if your custom page template is named `template-foobar.php`, and the dynamic sidebar name is `footer-text-widget`:

   ```
   if ( 'template-foobar.php' == get_page_template() ) { 
       dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-text-widget' ); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Chip's answer, if you want to go down the plugin route, I sometimes use one called 'Custom Sidebars' (somewhat conveniently).

You'll be able to create your own sidebar (Appearance -> Custom Sidebars), and then add widgets to it (Appearance -> Widgets).

Then, you'll need to go to the page in question (Pages -> All Pages -> [Your Page]), and look for a new box called Sidebars that lets you select the sidebar you just created.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter, example:

```
function remove_the_widget( $regions ){
    if(is_page('12')) {
        $key = array_search('text-3', $regions['sidebar']);
        if($key !== FALSE) {
            unset($regions['sidebar'][$key]);
        }
    }
    return $regions;
}
add_filter('sidebars_widgets', 'remove_the_widget');
```